# FORWARD_NULL after derefencing null?

Tags: c#, static-analysis, registrykey

I have this line of code:

```
this.Path = pathLookUpLocation.GetValue(RegLookupKey, null).ToString();
```

When I run static analysis tool (Coverity) on my code I get a FORWARD_NULL here, saying that I am dereferencing null here. I am having trouble understanding what that means and how I would go about fixing it?

this.Path is a string, pathLookUpLocation is a RegistryKey, RegLookupKey is a string.

Comment: It would really help if you could give us some hints about the types involved...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose `pathLookUpLocation` is of type `RegistryKey`.

The reason for this message is that your code will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the value with the key specified by `RegLookupKey` is not found. This happens, because you pass `null` as the second parameter to [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk88y0s0.aspx). The second parameter is the default value that is returned if the key can't be found.

Fix it by changing it to `string.Empty`:

```
this.Path = pathLookUpLocation.GetValue(RegLookupKey, string.Empty).ToString();
```